# Executing a shell script with sudo / no password

Tags: sudo

I got this line in `sudoers`:

```
Cmnd_Alias NVIDIA = /sbin/sh -c 'echo ON > /proc/acpi/bbswitch; modprobe nvidia; modprobe nvidia_drm modeset=1'

user ALL=(ALL) ALL, NOPASSWD: /sbin/systemctl suspend,NVIDIA
```

My `sudo -l` shows me:

```
sudo -l
User user may run the following commands on devbox:
    (ALL) ALL, NOPASSWD: /sbin/systemctl suspend, /sbin/sh -c 'echo ON > /proc/acpi/bbswitch; modprobe nvidia; modprobe nvidia_drm modeset\=1'
```

Nevertheless if I try to run `/sbin/sh -c 'echo ON > /proc/acpi/bbswitch; modprobe nvidia; modprobe nvidia_drm modeset=1'` - I am still prompted to enter password.

I suspect there's something about `=` sign I have in the `modeset` argument for nvidia load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, make sure you *always* use `visudo` to edit `/etc/sudoers`. It will perform syntax checks for you so that it's less likely you end up shutting yourself out.

Now, use that command to remove the inappropriate first comma (between `ALL` and `NOPASSWD`):

```
(ALL) ALL NOPASSWD: /sbin/systemctl suspend
```

Next, know that your `modeset` command is too complex to define directly and reliably in the `sudoers` file. Consider this command (with or without `sudo`):

```
sh -c 'date >/tmp/date'
```

The quotes will be parsed by your own (interactive) shell and the quoted string passed as a single word. The `sh` will see two arguments, `-c` and `date >/tmp/date`; the quotes are never seen by the command. Similarly, the quotes here will never be seen by `sudo` either:

```
sudo sh -c 'date >/tmp/date'
```

The `sudo` will see three arguments `sh`, `-c`, and `date >/tmp/date`.

Therefore my suggestion would be that you create a short shell script that performs the required action, and add *that* to your `sudoers` file. (Run the following block of commands as root - use `sudo -s` to get a root shell.)

```
cat >/usr/local/bin/modeset1 <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
echo ON > /proc/acpi/bbswitch
modprobe nvidia
modprobe nvidia_drm modeset=1
EOF

chown root /usr/local/bin/modeset1
chmod a=rx,u+w /usr/local/bin/modeset1
```

Now add this line to `sudoers` using the `visudo` command:

```
(ALL) ALL NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/modeset1
```

Once `/usr/local/bin` has been added to your `$PATH` you just invoke it with your usual user account as a standard command,

```
sudo modeset1
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing, looks like passing arguments to `sudo` is tricky, so setting up a shell script and referencing it in the `sudoers` works fine.